Are skilled wizards or witches better at controlling another person's wand?
Building on this question I come to the following assumptions:

With some exceptions, wands choose their own masters.
Most wands stay loyal to their original owners.
Using another person's wand yields subpar results.

Now, is subduing/ controlling another person's wand a matter of skill, i.e. highly skilled wizards/ witches perform better? I.e. if wizard X's wand is taken and stays loyal to wizard X, would highly-skilled witch A be better at using wizard X's wand than average-skilled witch B?
Spoilers for the first Fantastic Beasts movie ahead:

 A case study would be Grindelwald while impersonating Percival Graves. While he was in the possession of the Elder Wand (which I do NOT consider representative for my question), he was most likely using Percival Graves' wand (also see this discussion). Now, if Grindelwald uses Graves' wand, it should yield poor(er) results. This lead me to thinking Grindelwald needed to be quite adept at subduing Graves' wand to not raise suspicion and that controlling other person's wand may be a skill issue. Are there any sources to back that hypothesis?


Since Grindlewald subdued (or killed) Graves, the wand's loyalty would be to its new master

I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

I see the confusion and added another assumption and a paraphrased question. With a few exceptions, wands do not change loyality, as discussed in the linked question.

Why would a less powerful or less competent witch be better at using a stolen wand? I remain confused.

Oh my, English language... I hope this edit clarified your confusion.

Hmm. Voldemort tries to force the Elder Wand to do his bidding and it results in the wand suffering damage...

"...the Elder Wand (which I do NOT consider representative for my question)..." -OP

Why wouldn't a more powerful or competent witch be better at using a stolen wand?

I know it seems logical, but it might not be a matter of skill but more of "the wand likes you more because you share characteristics with Wizard X" or something else.
